# Прикрепление файлов к письму MODX через AjaxForm

Tags: ajax, modx

пытаюсь сделать отправку файлов через ajaxform на cmas MODX
Скажу сразу, отправка работает, все супер. Файлы не прикрепляются

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="formTitle" value="[[*pagetitle]]">
    <input type="hidden" name="formLink" value="[[++site_url]][[*uri]]">

    <div class="db mgb">
        <label for="subject" class="label fs2x db sure">Телефон:</label>
        <input placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" type="tel" name="formPhone" id="formPhone" required>
    </div>

    <div class="db mgb">
        <label for="message" class="label fs2x db sure">Сообщение:</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст Вашего сообщения..." name="formMessage" style="min-height:100px" rows="8"
                  required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="db mgb">
        <label for="subject" class="label fs2x db">Прикрепленные файлы:</label>
        <input name="attachment[]" type="file" multiple>
    </div>

    <button class="btn default" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="formSubmit">
        <span>Отправить сообщение</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Вставка в страницу:

```
[[!AjaxForm?
&snippet = `ajaxHandler`
&form = `contactsForm`
]]
```

Обработчик:

```
<?php
$emails = array(
    'mail@gmail.com', //тут моя почта
);

$action = (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) ? $_POST['formSubmit'] : '';

switch ($action) {
    case "formSubmit":
        if (empty($_POST['formPhone'])) {
            return $AjaxForm->error('Укажите Ваш телефон, по которому с Вами можно связаться.');
        }

        $phoneNums = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $_POST['formPhone']);

        if (!(strlen($phoneNums) == 11)) {
            return $AjaxForm->error('Укажите Ваш телефон в правильном формате.');
        }

        if (empty($_POST['formMessage'])) {
            return $AjaxForm->error('Укажите Ваше сообщение.');
        }

        $modx->getService('mail', 'mail.modPHPMailer');
        $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_FROM, $modx->getOption('emailsender'));
        $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_FROM_NAME, $modx->getOption('site_name'));
        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $modx->mail->address('to', $email);
        }

        $the_file = '';
        //Если пользователь выбрал файл для отправки
        if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
            // Закачиваем файл
            $path = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
            if (copy($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
                $the_file = $path;
            }
        }

        if (empty($the_file)) {
            $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_SUBJECT, 'Обратный звонок с поддомена Luxorta');
            $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_BODY, '
            <p><strong>Страница с которой отправлено: </strong>' . $_POST['formTitle'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Ссылка на страницу с которой отправлено: </strong>' . $_POST['formLink'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Телефон: </strong>' . $_POST['formPhone'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Сообщение: </strong>' . $_POST['formMessage'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Файлы: </strong>' . $_POST['attachment'] . '</p>
        ');

            $modx->mail->setHTML(true);
            if (!$modx->mail->send()) {
                return $AjaxForm->error('Ошибка отправки!');
            }
            $modx->mail->reset();

            return $AjaxForm->success('Сообщение успешно отправлено');
            break;
        } else {
            // эта часть кода отвечает за отправку сообщений с вложениями
            // читаем отправляемый файл в строку
            $fp = fopen($the_file, "r");
            if (!$the_file) {
                die("Ошибка отправка письма: Файл $the_file не может быть прочитан.");
            }
            $file = fread($fp, filesize($path));
            fclose($fp);
            // удаляем временный файл
            unlink($path);
            $fileToSend = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

            $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_SUBJECT, 'Обратный звонок с поддомена Luxorta');
            $modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_BODY, '
            <p><strong>Страница с которой отправлено: </strong>' . $_POST['formTitle'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Ссылка на страницу с которой отправлено: </strong>' . $_POST['formLink'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Телефон: </strong>' . $_POST['formPhone'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Сообщение: </strong>' . $_POST['formMessage'] . '</p>
            <p><strong>Файлы: </strong>' . $fileToSend . '</p>
        ');

            $modx->mail->setHTML(true);
            if (!$modx->mail->send()) {
                return $AjaxForm->error('Ошибка отправки!');
            }
            $modx->mail->reset();

            return $AjaxForm->success('Сообщение успешно отправлено');
            break;
        }
}
```

FormIt дополнительно не использую. Если нужно, скажите (я новичок). Непонятно как в обработчике вставить в письмо файл

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно без FormIt

Answer (score 1):

Добавление аттача к письму перед его отправкой в общем случае происходит так:

```
$modx->mail->mailer->AddAttachment($file);
```

$file здесь -полный путь к файлу, не URL
Конечно нужно еще провалидировать полученный файл, примеры полезного кода можно взять,например, здесь: https://itchief.ru/modx/formit-files